# How two strings with same value in it are stored in memory?

Tags: c#

```
string first="Example";
string second="Example";
```

Both of strings have the same hash code and both references are same.

My Question is: Does these strings variables have a single copy of data in Memory Location?

```
string third="Example";
static string fourth="Example";
const string fifth="Example";
```

Is there any difference between above two sets?

Comment: In this case all variables reference the same string object because literal strings are added to the [string pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In addition to Tim, when using `new string("Example")` you´d create a new reference to a new instance.

Answer (score 5):

In this **specific example**, all the strings are different references *with the same value*, to a single `string` object. This is because the `ldstr` IL instruction interns literal strings and reuses them rather than allocate per `ldstr`.

You can check this with `ReferenceEquals(first, second)` etc.

Note that the `const` one is slightly more intersting because it is then turned into a literal `ldstr` **at the call-site**, and how the interning is shared can depend on assembly boundaries.

But: it is not true that *all* `"Example"` must be the same reference. Most other mechanisms of obtaining a string (from processing input data) will *not* look at the interned data, but will just construct a new string.

Comment: thanks for pointing out! I will have to read up on this topic^^

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i have one more thing to ask you .

`code StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("abcde");  
            string test2 = "abcde";  
            string test3 = String.Intern(test.ToString());   `

in the above snippet each has separate  reference even we intern them what is the difference among them

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar actually `test2` and `test3` are the same reference - although the intermediate string that `test.ToString()` returns is separate; when this goes through `string.Intern`, you get the same interned version that `test2` has obtained via `ldstr`. `test` isn't a `string` in the first place, so cannot be the same reference.

Comment: Hello 
Marc Gravell,
can we use operator overloading for strings

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar in what context? There are some operators already defined for `string`; since the `string` type is inbuilt, you can't add operators to it - but other types that you own can declare conversion, equality, etc operators that involve strings.